# How to access docker container on the web?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have google cloud VM instance running Ubuntu 18 and I have installed ngnix and pulled this docker image https://github.com/lensesio/fast-data-dev. But the problem is I cannot access container when i run following command

```
docker run -d -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081-8083:8081-8083 \
       -p 9581-9585:9581-9585 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=[VM_EXTERNAL_IP] \
       -e RUNNING_SAMPLEDATA=1 lensesio/fast-data-dev
```

It is supposed to work on myexternalip:3030 but it doesn't open. I assume because I have to expose docker ports to external web because

```
curl 0.0.0.0:3030
```

returns response. I opened mentioned ports in the command above in the firewall.

Comment: Is a firewall like ufw enabled on the Ubuntu VM?

Comment: what does docker logs say?

Comment: Fwiw, please don't expose Kafka or Zookeeper unauthorized access over the internet

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure those ports you expose in docker are opened *both* in the Instance and in the VPC firewall.

In Google Cloud you can deploy a container inside a Compute Engine instance when you create it (see [Deploying a container on a new vm instace](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#deploying_a_container_on_a_new_vm_instance)).

It is easier (and faster) than doing it on your own, and you all your container port mappings defined in the same place you open the firewall ports.

BTW - Don't use the IP address 0.0.0.0: it's the unspecified newtwork address.
It might be filtered silently by firewalls or routers. Use the loopback address - 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In order to expose the port 3030 on the public IP (VM_EXTERNAL_IP) at the Instance , at VPC level there must be a rule on the firewall for the specific protocol/port to allow it.[1]

A generic broad scope allow firewall rule definition would be [2]:

`gcloud compute --project=[PROJECT] firewall-rules create allow-lenses-io-3030 --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:3030 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0`

You can limit the scope of the rule as needed/wanted/required.[3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create

[3] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

Answer (score -1):

Ran this on my VM, and I got this error:

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

If you are getting the same error above, you would need to check the file permission by running this command

```
~$ ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
```

After changing the file permission to 666 by running this command below:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

This should be the file permission

```
srw-rw-rw- 1 root docker 0 Dec 17 14:40 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Then,  I was able to successfully run your command

```
docker run -d -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081-8083:8081-8083 -p 9581-9585:9581-9585 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=[VM_EXTERNAL_IP] -e RUNNING_SAMPLEDATA=1 lensesio/fast-data-dev
Unable to find image 'lensesio/fast-data-dev:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from lensesio/fast-data-dev
05e7bc50f07f: Pull complete 
476521bd3084: Pull complete 
c4c2aa517a1c: Pull complete 
7f1b06a24ab4: Pull complete 
bae2eaa88cbb: Pull complete 
2d9ee69ece21: Pull complete 
4da70d410da1: Pull complete 
59abe7119ed3: Pull complete 
ed6eaf2a0a19: Pull complete 
25aa81bc4e49: Pull complete 
8ccac59252e2: Pull complete 
225a5ca8c99d: Pull complete 
6d7f2dab62f4: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:a40302e35e1e11839bcfe12f6e63e0d665f098249e0ce9c111a2e212215f8841
Status: Downloaded newer image for lensesio/fast-data-dev:latest
051711522df0198d2f94825dee8d2556e137c7b31501b68cd73541ae8d4286d7
```

Comment: 1) don't chmod 666 the Docker socket 2) all you needed to do was `sudo docker run` 3) this doesn't answer how to externally access the container over the network